# Can WebSphere variables be used in extendedDocumentRoot?

Tags: websphere, websphere-6

Can variables be used in the `ibm-ext.xmi` file for the `extendedDocumentRoot` attribute on WebSphere 6.x?

It appears they are [available for Websphere 7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PK93292).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use WebSphere Variables for an extendedDocumentRoot in WebSphere Application Server version 6.1.  This option was added in WAS version 7.0 in fixpack 7.0.0.7.